# How to get Mouse-Entered Element ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Is there any solution to get object id while mouse entering it? 
Something like this:

```
mouseenter(function () {
alert(ObjectName);
});
```

MORE:
Suppose that I have tens of DIV in my page and I want to change their color when mouse entering them, so I won't do that till i know the object ID, On the other side I can not set mouse enter function for any of them separately.

Comment: `alert(event.target.id)`

Comment: what is mouseenter? is it the jquery event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have divs:

```
<div id="div1" class="list-item"></div>
<div id="div2" class="list-item"></div>
<div id="div3" class="list-item"></div>
```

With jQuery just do this to get the id:

```
$('.list-item').mouseenter(function (event) {
  alert(event.target.id);
});
```

That said, you don't have to know the id to change the color because `event.target` is the `div` you want to change, I assume. So just do something like:

```
$('.list-item').mouseenter(function (event) {
  $(event.target).css({backgroundColor: '#F00'});
});

$('.list-item').mouseleave(function (event) {
  $(event.target).css({backgroundColor: ''});
});
```

Comment: how to use it? should it contained of $(document).ready or sth else?

Comment: @A.Mokhtari You have to attach the event handler somewhere. Are you using jQuery? What are you trying to achieve exactly? What are you wanting to bind the event handler to?

Comment: Yes I am using jquery ... It's better to edit my post to explain more

Comment: @A.Mokhtari If this answer solved your problem I'd sure appreciate it if you mark it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

if mouseenter is the jquery event handler then

```
$("<selector>").mouseenter(function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```